# the closer humans get to them

Tags: comparative-constructions

How do you analyze "the closer humans get to them" in relation to the rest of the sentence? I thought it requires a comparative in the main clause, but there's none.

> Have you ever heard a rattlesnake rattling up close? It turns out the venomous reptiles change the frequency of their rattle **the closer humans get to them**.

Answer (score 2):

The phrasing of the cited text is a bit sloppy. The writer is trying to draw a parallel between two "gradeable" actions (the snake changing the frequency of its rattle, and the human getting closer).

But there's a clash between "changing frequency" and "getting closer", because only the second has the implied ***direction of change*** - whereas the whole *point* of drawing the parallel is to note that ***the same kind of change*** happens to both (usually, as one increases, so does the other). To fix this, we just need to change the verb ***change*** to something with an implied "direction" that can vary in proportion to "getting closer"...

> *...venomous reptiles **increase** the frequency of their rattle the closer humans get to them.*

(I haven't looked it up, but I bet they don't ***decrease*** the rattle frequency as you get closer! :)

Comment: Is this OK? "The pool darkened the more ink he poured in."

Answer (score 1):

The comparison should be made with parallel structures.

Using comparatives:
*they rattle faster as humans get closer*
*the closer humans get, the faster they rattle*

Without comparatives:
*they increase the frequency of their rattle as humans approach*

Comment: Is this a "parallel structure"? "The signals warning you how close an object is behind you beep faster the closer you are to it."

Comment: Really parallel would be *the closer you are, the faster they beep*. but as stated, at least it uses two comparatives *[signals] beep faster the closer you are to it*.

Comment: Another parallel expression is *the closer you come, the faster they beep.* or *they beep faster as you come closer*.